# How is a tenure-track appointment in Sweden?

Tags: faculty-application, tenure-track, europe, sweden

I have been offered a tenure-track position in Sweden starting this September. I am very excited. Due to both cultural and working system differences, many things are unclear to me. I do not want to ask them to reveal my over-excitement. Besides, some of my ideas as you can see below might be silly and premature.

Can you narrate a typical appointment procedure?

For example, I have these silly questions:

1. Is there any formal inauguration? Do I need academic gown?
2. Do I need to deliver a lecture about my previous works?
3. What documents should I give to the administration? Should I give my awards and other certificates of merit?
4. Should I teach a course right in September?
5. Will I immediately given a space to set up my lab?
6. When can I get graduate students to start research?

Sorry for the silly questions but you have no idea about the combination of over-excitement and chaos in my head right now.

Comment: I would say: 1) no, 2-6) it depends. At my department, you'd probably be encouraged to present some research at the weekly seminar series. You'd probably not start teaching immediately, but that also depends on staffing. I think these are legitimate questions to ask your potential employer.

Comment: No offense, but it rather questionable logic that you ask a forum about administrative details that are clearly case-by-case and often based on negotiation , and not the university just to hide your “excitement “.

Comment: Please post the answer based on your experience.